# Creating umbrella framework with Another Framework binary/archive with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I have 2 frameworks: `A` and `B`.

Framework `A` is just a binary, archived version of the framework (`A.framework`) that is currently not available on Cocoapods. A is a dependency of my framework, B.

I want to use A in my project. I dragged the `A.framework` file into my project and it builds fine. When I try to publish my framework B, I'm faced with the error: `ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  A/A.framework/Headers/AFrameworkHeaders.h:10:9: error: 'A/AFrameworkHeaders.h.h' file not found`

I suspect that the binary `A.framework` is not getting copied correctly or something.. Can anyone shed any light to this?

Comment: Just put frameworkA in `vendored_framework` in frameworkB podspec?